# python mock test actual and expected is equal but fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm mock testing with a global variable, which is I am patching as fixture called `bucket_fixture`

```
s3_client_object_fixture.client.get_object.assert_called_once_with(Bucket=bucket_fixture, key=filename)
```

the error message I am getting is:

```
    E       AssertionError: expected call not found.
    E       Expected: get_object(Bucket=<MagicMock name='BUCKET' id='140544436587440'>, key='test.tsv')
    E       Actual: get_object(Bucket=<MagicMock name='BUCKET' id='140544436587440'>, Key='test.tsv')
```

the Mock object has the the same id, I am assuming its the same instance, so why is it failing?

Comment: nvm.  the cause of the issue is this part

```key='test.tsv' != Key='test.tsv'```

Comment: You have two different keywords: `Key` and `key`, so they differ, of course.